# How to write a letter to request a new monitor?

Tags: american-english, email, letter-writing

I'm not good to write an letter to request a monitor for coding because currently I'm using old monitor which sized 17 inch thus I want to change to monitor screen 24 inch but I don't know how to begin with the formal letter or email because I difficult to description of disadvantage and advantages of old monitor and new monitor in English.

If you have any tutorial about this please keep me a link.

Thanks you very much for help

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. StackExchange is not well-suited for writing or editorial advice, as there are countless different ways to express an idea and it is a matter of opinion as to which will be the best way. Please review the [help center](http://english.stackexchange.com/help) for guidance on what kinds of questions are on-topic here. Our sister site for [English Language Learners](http://ell.stackexchange.com/) may also be of interest, though they are similarly unable to give writing advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Begin with a greeting.  This used to go "Dear Mr. Smith," but nowadays Dear is rare.  If you've ever gotten an email from Mr. John Smith that ended with simply John you can open with simply "John,".  People often don't go by their exact legal name and use some prefered variation.  If you can discover that it's better to use it.

State your purpose.  Be positive.  Focus on the good not the bad.

If you're writing to someone who's job is to fill the order you only need to give your specifications.  State them clearly.

If you're writing to a decision maker you need to be persuasive.  Express the idea that a 24 inch monitor is more modern updated equipment.  Express the impact on productivity without overstating it.  Express the minimal cost.

Close the email with your prefered name.

If you can get a friend to proof read it.

Unfortunately, composing and proofreading are not what we do at ELU.

As for a tutorial try [this](http://www.englishtown.com/community/channels/article.aspx?articleName=184-email) or just search for "writing professional emails"

Comment: Be sure to mention the low resolution of your current monitor. Something like: "A resolution of 640X480 in not sufficient to work efficiently or effectively with modern GUI based operating systems".

Comment: That is ok because I connect my laptop to my own monitor at home with screen size: 24 inch so I just want to request a new monitor at my company. about resolution is ok this laptop can supported high resolution 
Thanks for your idea